# RxJava. Why operators like timer(), delay(), etc. use the computation scheduler by default?

Tags: rx-java

The computation scheduler is needed for CPU-intensive tasks, so why does RxJava use it for delaying in operators like `delay()`, `timer()`, `interval()`, etc.?

1. Is delaying a CPU intensive task? Can we have 100 timers at once if the computation scheduler is limited to 10 threads?
2. Is it wrong to use the IO scheduler there?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are always overloads provided where you can specify the scheduler you want.

Second, many uses are for when there is a need for delay or periodicity, but once the timer fires, you have a full fledged computation-intensive workload right behind.

> Can we have 100 timers at once if the computation scheduler is limited to 10 threads?

You don't need as many threads as timers because waiting is not done by sleeping on the timer threads individually. Waiting is done by possibly sleeping on one thread until there is an immediate task or the time elapsed for the next timed task. This is a pretty standard way of doing arbitrary number of timers and is handled by Java's `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

> Is it wrong to use the IO scheduler there?

Using `io()` usually ends up having more threads than cores. Mixing computational tasks and blocking/io tasks can result in response latency problems. Also you can't limit the `io()` scheduler's thread count.

On a similar note, using a `single()` as default is prone to leaving all timed computations on a single thread as users forget to switch to `computation()`.

Using `newThread()` is wasting resources when timers are thrown away too quickly or there are too many of them.